# How call SQL Function in VB. NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, function, ado.net

How can be call a SQL function which takes two parameters? I want memorize the returning value in a variable.

The function is:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [CheckPwd](  @User nvarchar(50),  @Pwd nvarchar(50)) 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RES int
DECLARE @PWD_DB varbinary(255)

  IF (@User is not null and @User != '' and @Pwd is not null and @Pwd != '' )
begin
    SELECT  @PWD_DB = password FROM UserTable WHERE username = @User
        SET @PwdRES = pwdcompare(@Pwd, @PWD_DB )
end
  ELSE
        SET @PwdRES = 0

RETURN @RES
END
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about the function name, return value, and the parameter types?

Comment: I want a general approch! You really need function name?

Comment: Do you mean a stored procedure?

Comment: You can search for general approaches on the internet. This site is more for specific problems that you need help solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with a stored-procedure, with plain SQL it's similar.

```
Public Function getFooID(param1 As Int32, param2 As String)As Int32
    Dim returnValue As Int32
    Using con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("dbo.Foo", con)
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", param2)
             Try
                con.Open()
                returnValue = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' a good place to insert logging functionality '
                log.Error("Error in getFooId: " + ex.Message);
                ' note that Throw keeps the stacktrace unlike Throw ex '
                Throw
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return returnValue 
End Sub
```

[`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: @StingyJack: Yes, a good place to insert logging functionality. Just wanted to show that a `Try-Catch` can be useful even in case of a `Using` statement. Because `Throw` keeps the stacktrace it doesn't hurt anyway.

Comment: Please note that `throw` also messes with the stack trace in certain conditions: If the exception happened in the code inside the `try` (and not in a method that is called in that code), the stack trace will NOT contain the original line but the line of the `throw`. Actually, I just created a test case that even messes with the stack trace when the Exception occurred in a method called inside the try block.